# Stop background fetch task iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, task, background-process

I'm using `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` for background fetch.
When I want to start `backgroundFetch` i use `UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)`.

But i want to stop this background fetch. **How can i do this ?**

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you mean with "stop this background fetch". But to prevent the `performFetch` from being called, you can use `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInteval` with value `backgroundFetchIntervalNever`.
Note though, that all those interfaces are deprecated

Comment: @fishinear When I get FALSE from the server, I want to stop the background fetching process. And start again when necessary.
I know that they are deprecated, I will use two methods for older versions of iOS and for iOS13+

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623125-application. It says explicitly what to do when the fetch was unsuccessful.

Comment: @fishinear Thank. All tasks are running fine, I just wanted to know how to stop this process)
You can write your comment as an answer to the question, I will mark it as correct